# ArgumentError in Rails::WelcomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails. While creating a new application and starting `http://localhost:3000/` I am getting following error:

```
wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Full trace is as follows:

actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `initialize'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb:25:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:179:in `action_method?'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:230:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:17:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:130:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__170541183__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Can anyone help me with the solution ?

**EDIT:**

My welcome_controller.rb contains:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

My routes.rb contains:

```
Railsgirls::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"
end
```

Comment: Can you post your Welcome Controller `index` action and also the error implies you are providing an argument somewhere and it does not take any arguments hence the (1 for 0) argument error

Comment: which is your ruby and rails version.. Can you just post your gem file

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside routes instead of `get`:

```
root to: 'welcome#index'
```

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't seem to work. Do I need to perform any other step after editing routes.rb ?

Comment: Do You get the same error? If error is the same are You getting it since creating Your app or it started to happen after You added some code ? Try to create a new rails app and try to start it without adding any custom code - is it still throwing an error ? Also why You are using so old version for a new project ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you use `ruby 1.9.1` with `rails 4.0.0` but `rails 4` only works with `ruby 1.9.3+`
http://rubyonrails.org/download

Answer (score 0):

In your routes use

```
get "welcome#index"
```

Otherwise you're declaring a namespace.

Use

```
rake routes
```

to see how your routes are declared

Comment: Considering he is opening localhost:3000, he probably wants root method instead of get.

Comment: true, but one step at the time

Comment: I tried this as well. Doesn't seem to work. And `rake routes` return: Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
root GET / welcome#index